# Are there any cross-browser JavaScript **queryable** cache implementations?

Tags: javascript, caching

Are there any cross-browser JavaScript **queryable** cache implementations?

The querying should remain accurate across browser sessions i.e. in-memory solutions are not acceptable.

Ideally I'd just query the browser's built-in cache, however I can't find any cross-browser mechanism for doing this. Consequently, a JavaScript library that uses its own caching mechanism would be acceptable as long as it's cross-browser (i.e. not *exclusively* using File System API etc.)

By queryable I mean that I can check to see to see if a particular URL is cached *without* kicking off a download for said resource.

**Motivation**

I'm working with three.js and displaying a library of models that can be placed in a larger scene. The models are downloaded on demand. I would like a way of indicating which models have already been downloaded.

**Note**

I've read about HTML5's Application Cache and `window.localStorage`, however I don't believe that they (on their lonesome) are a solution. To my knowledge Application Cache isn't queryable, and I believe that `window.localStorage` can only reliably store 5 MB of data per domain.

Comment: @ScottKaye Sorry, I should have added that to my "Note" section. To my knowledge IndexedDB is also limited to 5 MB so isn't suitable for storing large resources. **EDIT:** Whoops, looks like you must have realised the same thing and removed your comment.

Comment: Hmm, there's a lot of conflicting (outdated?) information regarding IndexedDB. Maybe it could be a solution...